# Find geometries with coordinates that do not belong in projection

Tags: postgis

I was recently supplied data in a shape file projection EPSG:4326. I imported this into my PostGIS database and then tried to transform to 3857. I got the error

`ERROR:  transform: couldn't project point (-99762.4 -2.87277e+006 0): latitude or longitude exceeded limits (-14)`

Even after applying `st_force2d` and `st_makevalid` I still couldn't transform until I managed to track down a delete the one geometry that was "out of bounds" for Lat/Lng.

My question is: how do I easily find geometries that don't fit in the current projections envelope?

Answer (score 1):

In case of [4326](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/4326/) this should work:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE 
  (st_x(geom) NOT BETWEEN -180 AND 180) 
  OR  
  (st_y(geom) NOT BETWEEN -90 AND 90) ;
```

Comment: The data consists of polygons, even though the error reports the first point that it got stuck on. With a slight modification this will handle polygons. Ideally I am looking for a generic way of handling any projection. Probably by first getting the projections envelope?

Comment: @Derek, see my other answer below

Answer (score 1):

(I would have left this as a comment, but since I can't, here it is.)

This answer could be helpful:
[Get projection limits from Postgis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35014630/get-projection-limits-from-postgis)

Basically:

1. PostGIS doesn't know about a projection's bounds and you would need to make a new table to collect it.
2. Even if the value is contained in a projection's limits, it doesn't mean that it is right for this projection. This method can only ensure that the transform process will proceed and get you a result, it can not ensure that the data is correct.

Answer (score 0):

For a more generic solution, you could use a custom transform function which catch the error:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION transform_safe(geom geometry, srid int) RETURNS geometry AS $$
BEGIN
  IF ST_Srid(geom) = 0 THEN
    RAISE Exception 'Input geometry has unknown (0) SRID';
  END IF;
  BEGIN
    RETURN ST_Transform(geom, srid);
  EXCEPTION WHEN internal_error THEN
    RAISE WARNING '%: %',SQLSTATE,SQLERRM;
  END;
  RETURN NULL;
END;

$$
language plpgsql;
```

This behaves the same as ST_Transform but returns NULL if the coordinates are out of bounds.

In example, so could you identify the records with invalid coordinates:

```
SELECT id FROM polygon_table WHERE transform_safe(geom) IS NULL AND geom IS NOT NULL;
```